# What happens to deployed Java application?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

code that will be encrypting some data using AES.

Encryption has a limit for key strength and by placing the unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files in the correct location. One can use stronger key for AES.

Do every computer uses this software need to do the same (place this policy files) or they won't need it?

Comment: By strength, do you mean the size of keys?

Comment: yes, size of the key!

Comment: My suggestion is  use bouncycastle frame work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do every computer uses this software need to do the same (place this policy files)

Yes.

Comment: "Yes" is hardly an answer. I'm aware that this is a poorly asked question and maybe you feel it doesn't deserve a better answer, but then you should have posted this as a comment. If you're going to post an answer, at least include a short explanation and maybe describe some alternatives...

Comment: @l4mpi I disagree entirely. It answers the question completely. There are no alternatives and there is in fact nothing else to said about it. If you think otherwise you can always post your own answer so it in turn can be commented on, voted on, etc. It is to be noted that the OP evidently doesn't agree with you either. Nor do I think it a poorly asked question, nor that it doesn't deserve a better answer. These are all your own unsolicited opinions and they have nothing to do with what I have written here. If you want to comment on the question there are proper ways to do that as well.

Comment: @EJP Well, I disagree with your disagreement. First, SO is for questions useful to a larger audience - while a "yes" may be enough for OP it certainly won't suffice for a general audience; thus it can never fit SO's quality standards IMO. Second, there is always more to be said about it, for example why this is so. Also, "there are no alternatives" is (1) plain wrong (I could write my own algorithm that wouldn't be restricted by some policy files) and (2) a fact that would be useful to include in the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I think I just thought of an alternative - can't you bundle the app with a JRE with the policy files already installed? Also, re "bad question" - maybe bad was too strong of a word (there's certainly many worse questions on here) but it's far from a good question. It has a duplicate; meaning resarch on SO was lacking. Furthermore, the first revision of the question was somewhat unclear and not formulated all that well.

Comment: @Ampi He didn't ask about writing his own algorithm. He asked about using the AES implementation in the JRE. Deploying a JRE with your application doesn't alter the answer. The .policy files still have to be deployed, one way or the other. Your complaints about the question should be posted as comments to the question, not this answer. Your statement that this is 'hardly an answer' remains false. I note that the OP has just accepted it.